# RegEx in the select for DB2

Tags: regex, select, db2

I have a table with one column having a large json object in the format below. The column datatype is VARCHAR

```
column1
--------
{"key":"value",....}
```

I'm interested in the first value of the column data

in regex I can do it by `.*?:(.*),.*` with group(1) giving me the value

How can i use it in the select query

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that, it's bad database design. Shred the keys and values to their own table as columns, or use the XML data type. XML would work fine because you can index the structure well, and you can use XPATH queries on the data. XPATH supports regexp natively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression with xQuery, you just need to call the function matches from a SQL query or a FLORW query.

This is an example of how to use regular expressions from SQL:

```
db2 "with val as (
 select t.text
 from texts t
 where xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches(\$TEXT,''^[A-Za-z 0-9]*$'')') as integer) = 0
)
select * from val"
```

For more information:

- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfnmat.html
- http://angocadb2.blogspot.fr/2014/04/regular-expressions-in-db2.html

Answer (score 0):

DB2 doesn't have any built in regex functionality, unfortunately.  I did find an article about how to add this with libraries:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301stolze/0301stolze.html

Without regexes, this operation would be a mess.  You *could* make a function that goes through the string character by character to find the first value.  Or, if you will need to do more than this one operation, you *could* make a procedure that parses the json and throws it into a table of keys/values.  Neither one sounds fun, though.

Comment: That is false. DB2 does not provide a scalar function to solve Regular Expressions, however DB2 DOES provide the function matches in XQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 for z/OS you will have to pass the variable to XMLQUERY with the PASSING option

```
db2 "with val as (
 select t.text
 from texts t
 where xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches($TEXT,''^[A-Za-z 0-9]*$'')'
               PASSING t.text as "TEXT") as integer) = 0
)
select * from val"
```